# Error inflating class androidx.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, androidx, android-navigationview, material-components, material-components-android

I didn't initialize components in my StorageActivity thinking that the problem was there and when I rerun the program I still the same error. Pardon my english

NOTE: I am using androidX

> RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.shopeeproject/com.example.shopeeproject.StorageActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML
>   file line #23: Error inflating class
>   androidx.design.widget.NavigationView

MY XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StorageActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="#000000"
        app:itemTextColor="#000000"
        app:menu="@menu/menu">

    </androidx.design.widget.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout >
```

Comment: androidx.design.widget.NavigationView doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you are migrated to androidX, then you have to use material components: `com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView`

Since there is no library with `'androidx.design.widget.NavigationView'`

And to use material components you have to include dependency in gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```